# How to save query results in a Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have never used SQL before and I am trying to do something that should be simple, but it is taking hours to solve. I would like to download a table that is in a project at Google Cloud Platform. It is asked: "Choose where to save the results data from the query" and then I choose: "CSV(Google Drive) Save up to 1GB...". However, I get this message:

```
Table dataset_reference { project_reference { project_id: "escolas-259115" gaia_id: 777399094185 } dataset_id: "_31e2c29542f3fa3caf4d6d069271a277dce8d215" dataset_uuid: "9872dc9f-2c66-4088-b7b1-b949e7541f07" } table_id: "anon76eccaf0_a96b_4617_8a3c_c2d5ee734662" table_uuid: "76eccaf0-a96b-4617-8a3c-c2d5ee734662" too large to be exported to a single file. Specify a uri including a * to shard export. See 'Exporting data into one or more files' in https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data.
```

Here is the code that I am using:

```
SELECT
  ano,
  estado_abrev,
  id_municipio,
  causa_basica,
  idade,
  genero,
  raca_cor,
  numero_obitos
FROM
  `basedosdados.br_ms_sim.municipio_causa_idade_genero_raca`
```

As I said, I have never worked with SQL before.

Comment: Did you read the link in your error message? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you try to achieve is for exporting the table. Here, you want to export a query result.

You can achieve this like that

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://mybucket/transformed/sales-*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT
  ano,
  estado_abrev,
  id_municipio,
  causa_basica,
  idade,
  genero,
  raca_cor,
  numero_obitos
FROM
  `basedosdados.br_ms_sim.municipio_causa_idade_genero_raca`
```